# How to run Python and HTML together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

I am trying to create a simple tool (hopefully it is simple) that uses Python and HTML to perform some basic tasks.

I have this in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")

form=cgi.FieldStorage()

if "language" not in form:
    print("<h1>No option chosen</h1>")
else:
    text=form["language"].value
    print("<h1>The option chosen was:</h1>")
    print(text)
```

I have this in a text file, that is saved with an HTM extension.

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/examples/dropdown.py" method="POST">

    My favaourite programming language is
    <select name="language">
        <option value="c">C</option>
        <option value="python">Python</option>
        <option value="php">PHP</option>
        <option value="Java">Java</option>
    </select>
<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

The HTM file gives me a simple web page that lets me select items from a drop-down menu.

[image]

I am trying to get Python to interact with the HTM file, so I can allow a user to concatenate between 3-4 strings together, and then click a 'submit' button to request access to a few data sets, based on a combinations of items that a user selects from the drop-down menus.

Does this make sense?  Is this a good approach?  I'm looking at the sample code from the following URL.

http://raspberrywebserver.com/cgiscripting/web-forms-with-python.html

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Why not use a proper python web framework such as Flask or Django?

Comment: Sees a lots of experiment for django on Raspberry Pi successful, but OP may use an old device?

Comment: Looks OK, does it work as excepted?